# Check for mouseenter after page is loaded

Tags: javascript

One of my elements has a `mouseenter` event on it. The trouble is, I can't add the event until the dom is fully loaded, so I use something like:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    ${"my_element").observe("mouseenter", function() { ... }
});
```

Now, the user might be mousing over the element before the page is fully loaded, and so the event doesn't fire. They have to move their mouse to have it fire. How can I detect if I should fire the event after the page is fully loaded, so the user doesn't have to move their mouse?

Comment: Is this actually related to `jQuery`? The code you provided looks more like [`PrototypeJS`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/prototypejs/).

Comment: You are correct. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

the `$(document).ready(function(){` and `$(function(){` fire when the dom is ready, use `on` to attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements:

```
$(function(){
    ${"my_element").on("mouseenter", function() { ... }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is different from what I'm doing. I think the handler still wouldn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but [livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery) might help you. I *think* it attaches event handlers immediately, but it might wait until the DOM has been loaded, in which case it doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the effect you're applying, can you use a CSS rule to simulate it?

Something like

```
#my_element:hover { color: red }
```

Then in jQuery, in your `mouseenter` method, [jQuery.Rule](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/11/jqueryrule.html) to remove the rule.